# Не виден ajax прелоадер при отправке запроса

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Мучаюсь уже какой час над простым вопросом. При заполнении поля автоматически отправляется аякс запрос с долгой подгрузкой. Хочу в это время пустить прелоадер и пробую следующие:

```js
<script>
    $("#visiting_object").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 248399) {
            alert("тест");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $("#datepicker10").blur(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'Testdirect.php',
                    data: $('.passegAdd').serialize(),
                    
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#loading').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#request').html( result );
                         console.log(result);
                         /*
                        alert("У вас количество заявок больше 5");
                        document.getElementById("button34").style.display="none";*/
                    }
                });

                return true;

            });

        }
    });


</script>
```

```html
 <div id="loading" name="loading" class="windows8">
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_1">
            <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_2">
            <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_3">
            <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_4">
            <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_5">
            <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Что тут может быть не так, чет не понимаю(( Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Как минимум то, что вы в событии `change` создаете событие `blur`. Во время чего вы хотите показывать лоадер? При изменении значения или при потере фокуса?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Во время потери фокуса

Comment: Ну значит вынесите объявление события потери фокуса из события изменения.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Вынес, но мне кажется не в этом дело

Comment: Покажите, что у вас получилось. Отредактируйте вопрос. Потом скажите, что теперь не работает. И приведите `html` для `#datepicker10`.